# What to care about when using a load balancer?

Tags: php, apache2, load-balancing, haproxy

I have a web application written in PHP, is already deployed on an Apache server and works perfectly.

The application uses Mysql as db, session are saved in memcached server.

I am planning to move to an HAproxy environment with 2 servers.

What I know: I will deploy the application to the servers and configure HAproxy.

My question is: is there something I have to care about/change **in the code** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Are you trying to solve a performance or redundancy problem?

If your database (**MySQL**) and session handler (**memcached**) are running on one or more servers separate from the two **Apache** servers, then the only major thing your code will have to do differently is manage the forwarded IP addresses (via `X-FORWARDED-FOR`), and HAProxy will happily round robin your requests between Apache servers.

If your database and session handler are currently running on the *same server*, then you need to decide if the performance or redundancy problem you are trying to solve is with the database, the session management, or Apache itself.

The easiest solution, for a performance problem with a database/session-heavy web app, is to simply start by putting MySQL and memcached on the second server to separate your concerns. If this solves the performance problem you were having with one server, then you could consider the situation resolved.

If the above solution does not solve the performance problem, and you notice that Apache is having trouble serving your website files, then you would have the option of a "hybrid" approach where Apache would exist on both servers, but then you would also run MySQL/memcached on one of the servers. If you decided to use this approach, then you could use HAProxy and set a lower weight to the hybrid server.

If you are attempting to solve a *redundancy* issue, then your best bet will be to isolate each piece into logical groups (e.g. database cluster, memcached cluster, Apache cluster, and a redundant HAProxy pair), and add redundancy to each logical group as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue that you are going to run into is going to be related to php sessions. By default php sessions maintain state with a single server. When you add the second server into the mix and start load balancing connections to both of them, then the PHP session will not be valid on the second server that gets hit.

Load balancers like haproxy expect a "stateless" application. To make PHP stateless you will more than likely need to use a different mechanism for your sessions. If you do not/can not make your application stateless then you can configure HAProxy to do sticky sessions either off of cookies, or stick tables (source IP etc).

The next thing that you will run into is that you will loose the original requestors IP address. This is because haproxy (the load balancer) terminates the TCP session and then creates a new TCP session to apache. In order to continue to see what the original requstors IP address is you will need to look at using something like x-forwarded-for. In the haproxy config the option is:

option forwardfor

The last thing that you are likely to run into is how haproxy handles keep alives. Haproxy has acl's, rules that determine where to route the traffic to. If keep alives are enabled, haproxy will only make the decision on where to send traffic based on the first request.

For example, lets say you have two paths and you want to send traffic to two different server farms (backends):

somedomain/foo -> BACKEND_serverfarm-foo

somedomain/bar -> BACKEND_serverfarm-bar

The first request for somedomain/foo goes to BACKEND_serverfarm-foo. The next request for somedomain/bar also goes to BACKEND_serverfarm-foo. This is because haproxy only processes the ACL's for the first request when keep alives are used. This may not be an issue for you because you only have 2 apache servers, but if it is then you will need to have haproxy terminate the keep alive session. Haproxy has several options for this but these two make the most since in this scenario:

option forceclose

option http-server-close

The high level difference is that forceclose closes both the server side and the client side keep alive session. http-server-close only closes the server side keep alive session which allows the client to maintain a keepalive with haproxy.